# INotifyPropertyChanged not working for XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, inotifypropertychanged, xmlserializer

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a collection. The types in the collection implement INotifyPropertyChanged (textbook implementation from the MSDN page).

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

public string Name
    {
    get { return m_Name; }
    set { m_Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
```

I'm trying to understand when, how and why the PropertyChanged event actually gets fired. If I write code to use the Name property to change the string everything works, PropertyChanged is != NULL, and my DataGridView updates correctly. Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Server.Customers.Count; i++)
    {
    Server.Customers[i].Name = Server.Customers[i].Name + "!!";
    }
```

That's just a test, however, the way the collection should really update is via XML deserialization. The implementation for the serializer is very straighforward, and the code steps through the exactly the same Name property (calling NotifyPropertyChanged) as in the previous example. With one difference: PropertyChanged turns out to be NULL and is never invoked. Result: no update in my data binding.

I don't quite understand what's going on here. I never explicitly subscribe to PropertyChanged in the first place (and neither do any of the code examples I have found), yet it gets invoked correctly in the first example. How do I get this to work for my second example, where I deserialize my XML into the object?

Comment: can you post the xaml? where you are binding at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML serialization can't update an existing object, it always creates a new one when you deserialize. Since it's a new object, there isn't any handler for `PropertyChanged` yet, so the event isn't fired.

It doesn't make sense to listen to the `PropertyChanged` event of an object that is being created. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Right, that makes all the sense in the world. The setup is a simple server/client model that update each other via XML. But I can easily work around that in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Thomas's answer and add a few suggestions:

If you need to use `INotifyPropertyChanges` you definitely should go some other way to deserialize an object. You can use instance method like `InitializeFrom(string xml)` or `UpdateFrom(string xml)`. You create an object, subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event and latter you call `UpdateFrom(xml)` on existing object. So you will be notified of changes and keep the existing object alive. Here, you can implement the whole thing in the following way:

```
class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanges
{
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public void UpdateFrom(string xml)
    {
        MyClass deserialized = Deserialize(xml);

        // here you set all properties you have
        Name = deserialized.Name;
        // and all the rest properties...
    }

    private static MyClass Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I would modify `NotifyPropertyChanged` method so it would not fire when property value hadn't changed.